# Is this class Right ? Hope you'd help :)

Tags: php, class

I've been wondering if the following class is right :

This class should make a mysql connection after gathering data of course , it also does mysql's different manipulations such as 'select', 'insert', 'update','delete' ...etc

```
class MySQL {

        protected $hostname;
        protected $username;
        protected $password;
        protected $database;
        protected $t_prefix;
        protected $_connect;            
        protected $SQLquery;

    public function mysql () {

            $this->hostname = INNOPB_MYSQl_HOSTNAME;
            $this->username = INNOPB_MYSQl_USERNAME;
            $this->password = INNOPB_MYSQl_PASSWORD;
            $this->database = INNOPB_MYSQl_DATABASE;
            $this->t_prefix = INNOPB_MYSQL_T_PREFIX;

            return $this;

        }

        public function connect( ) {

        $this->_connect = mysql_connect( 
        $this->hostname,
        $this->username,
        $this->password
        ) or die ( mysql_error() );

        mysql_select_db( $this->database , $this->_connect ) or die ( mysql_error() );

    }

    public function select ( $WHAT, $FROM, $WHERE = '', $ORDERBY = '', $ORDER = '', $LIMIT = '' ) {

$FROM       = $this->t_prefix . $FROM;
$WHERE      = ( !$WHERE ) ? '': " WHERE $WHERE";
$ORDERBY    = ( !$ORDERBY ) ? '': " ORDER BY $ORDERBY";
$ORDER      = ( !$ORDER ) ? '': " $ORDER";
$LIMIT      = ( !$LIMIT ) ? '' : " LIMIT $LIMIT";
$FROM       =   str_replace( '"' , "'", $FROM );
$WHERE      =   str_replace( '"' , "'", $WHERE );
$ORDERBY    =   str_replace( '"' , "'", $ORDERBY );
$ORDER      =   str_replace( '"' , "'", $ORDER );
$LIMIT      =   str_replace( '"' , "'", $LIMIT );

$this->SQLquery = "SELECT $WHAT FROM $FROM$WHERE$ORDERBY$ORDER$LIMIT";
$this->SQLquery = mysql_query( $this->SQLquery );

return $this;

}

public function getQuery() { return $this->SQLquery; }

public function getRowsNum() { 

return mysql_num_rows( $this->SQLquery ); 

}

public function delete( $FROM, $WHERE, $deleteAll = false ) {

if ( !$FROM || !$WHERE ) :

else :

$FROM       = $this->t_prefix . $FROM;
$WHERE      = ( !$WHERE ) ? '': " WHERE $WHERE";
$FROM       =   str_replace( '"' , "'", $FROM );
$WHERE      =   str_replace( '"' , "'", $WHERE );

( $deleteAll ) ? $this->SQLquery = "DELETE FROM $FROM" : $this->SQLquery = "DELETE FROM $FROM$WHERE";
$this->SQLquery = mysql_query( $this->SQLquery );
return $this->SQLquery;

        endif;

    }


}
```

Comment: Does it work for you? Then it's right enough. Would I ever use it, no. I'd suggest looking at an ORM (doctrine).

Comment: why u doing this to yourself? why dont u use a ORM that s already out there. you will encounter lot of problems with this code in the long term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works then I think that would be fine, instead of doing a specific `connect()` you should use `function __construct()` so that it will connect to the DB automatically and then use `function __destruct()` to kill the connection after the class is finished being used.

Comment: yes, you're right ! i should've used __construct() & __destruct();

Thanks for your answer ! Good luck :)